# Quicksilver will not open on my Mac (OS 10.6). Can you help?

Tags: snow-leopard, mac, error, quicksilver, macos

I installed [Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/) and due to some problems I have with the "shelf" feature I decided to uninstall it (using [appCleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/)).

When I tried to install it again the application wouldn't install the second time and it gave me this option

> "The previous version of Quicksilver was located in "Quicksilver 3".
>   Would you like to move this new version to that location?"

I clicked "OK" and the QS logo came up but disappeared within seconds.

There is no file on my computer with the word "quicksilver"

Is there anything you can recommend I do?

I am new to the Mac (got it only 2 day ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the excerpt from Quicksilver's [User Manual](http://mysite.verizon.net/hmelman/Quicksilver.pdf) that should deal with your problem (note the "~" denotes your user account home directory):

The `Quicksilver.app` is usually in `/Applications/` or `~/Applications/`. When first used, the following per user files and folders are created:

- `~/Library/Application Support/Quicksilver/`
- `Actions.plist` - list of installed actions
- `Catalog.plist` - the configured catalog sources
- `Mnemonics.plist` - learned inputs, defaults and abbreviations
- `PlugIns.plist` - the list of available plug-ins and how they are configured
- `Triggers.plist` - the configured triggers
- `Caches/` - another cache folder
- `Indexes/` - folder of indexed items
- `PlugIns/` - installed plug-ins
- `Shelves/` - where items on the Shelf and clipboards are stored
- `Actions/` - not installed but create this folder to add scripts that implement actions
- `Templates/` - not installed but create this folder to use with the Make New... action
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.blacktree.Quicksilver.plist` - stores various preferences and internal state
- `~/Library/Caches/Quicksilver/` - stores various state in binary files

**To do a complete uninstall use the Uninstall Quicksilver button in the Application preferences, or remove the above files and folders.**

It can also be useful to move or rename these while trouble-shooting a problem. If you are having trouble installing plug-ins check that the owner of `~/Library/Application Support/Quicksilver/` is the current user and not System. If it’s not, change it and restart Quicksilver.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after taking all that off it is working. The problem is that when I installed it the second time it did not give me the application file (for me to run in the appcleaner) but it seems that it did create all the other files you mentioned above

Comment: Do you by any chance have any idea why the Shelf plugin does not work (it does not open at all)

Comment: I'm sorry, that I don't know. But you may want to manually clear everything out and ensure the app is installed properly before dealing with this "Shelf" feature. You can also head over to Lifehacker's article to learn more about using Shelf: http://lifehacker.com/111278/how-to-use-quicksilvers-shelf

Answer (score 0):

Quicksilver is activated by a hotkey. That's why the logo appeared then disappeared. I believe the default shortcut is <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: I know but It does not work